# A program crashing the SWI Prolog console

Tags: crash, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm running a Prolog program that I wrote (a proof tester in natural deduction), and when I run the program (run_all_tests('proof_tester.pl').) the program runs, prints stuff from my program in the console(I barely have time to see what), and then closes SWI Prolog. It just disappears, without a warning or error message or anything. What could this possibly be?

Comment: You're probably overflowing the stack with a predicate that is recursing to deeply and/or trying to use more than the available memory for the size of a generated list.

Comment: This clearly should never occur and may be a mistake for example in the engine or the console code. Please report it on the SWI mailing list. The system should never crash like this. If it runs out of a resource, it should throw an exception, as it does in the cases mentioned by @mbratch.

Comment: Are you sure that the program crashes? Could there be a call to `halt/0`or `halt/1` in the program that halts execution when the computations end? Could be that the output is supposed to be redirected to a file?

Comment: There was a "halt" at the end of the program, and when I removed it the program worked and didn't crash the console. However, I have another solution to the same problem(also without the halt) which still crashes the console. I had enough time to see 2-3 red warnings, but nothing else.

Comment: Maybe you can redirect the program output to a text file and post those warnings for further advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the console closes due to `halt` being invoked, it is not a "crash".

If you [run the program `swipl -s proof_tester.pl` from a command line](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=startpl) rather than the console, then if the code executes `halt`, your output will still be in the "terminal" window.

You may prefer to redirect messages from SWI-Prolog to a text file ([Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), [Linux](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php)), which you can then read at your leisure, using a text editor or other means.